# Access denied while trying to push_back to a list<int> in a loop

Tags: c++, list, access-denied, push-back

While studying C++ and playing around with lists, I started experiencing some weird behavior, which I was able to isolate to the following piece of code:

```
#include <list>

int main() {
    std::list<int> ls;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        ls.push_back(1);
    }
}
```

I am able to compile this code but, when I try to run it, "Access denied" is printed to the prompt and the program is terminated. Sometimes, when I run the executable, the .exe file will disappear from the file system and I will be unable to create a new file with the same name in that folder, even if I delete and recreate the folder.

Some notes:

- The minimum number of iterations on the loop that I am able to reproduce this error is 10. Any lower than that the program runs fine.
- I am running this on Windows 10, using the Microsoft compiler.
- The error only occurs if I specify the /MT option. If I specify /MTd, /MD or /MDd the program runs fine. (Failing to specify any of these options also causes the problem. That's how I found the problem in the first place)
- If I try to specify /Z7, /Zi or /ZI the problem does not occur. (So I cannot debug it)
- I have tried disassembling the code generated by compiling with /MT and /MD to see if I could spot any differences. There were some small differences in the generated codes, but I couldn't tell if they were responsible for this behavior.(I know almost nothing of assembly)
- Microsoft Compiler version: Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Versão 19.10.25019 para x86 (my windows is in Portuguese)
- If I place an std::cout anywhere in the code the problem stops.
- If I use other containers, the problem does not occur.

Is this a bug in the compiler or is there something I am missing?

Comment: unable to reproduce.  Code works on Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: As soon as I get home I will download some other compilers to see if I can reproduce this in other compilers. At the moment I only have the Microsoft compiler on my machine and my Ubuntu VM is not starting.

Comment: Are you running as Administrator?  Are the folders read & write permission?

Comment: Sounds like an external issue that has nothing to do with your program, like an overzealous virus checker.

Comment: Unable to reproduce with MSVC 19.11.25507.1 x64.

Comment: This looks like an issue with your OS, your hardware, your compiler installation, or your AV software - the C++ code is perfectly fine.

Comment: The folder permissions are ok, running as Administrator did not work also. I'll try disabling AV

Comment: Ok... definetly the AV. Bitdefender is detecting the file as malicious for some reason. If you want to make your comment an answer I will gladly accept it @RetiredNinja and Neil Butterworth

Comment: Antivirus software that try to detect how common an executable is will likely quarantine your executables since they will not be common.. Also a sandbox mode tends to prevent applications like this from functioning.